# Android: Listview wont start new class fixed

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

**EDIT: It works now 
It does work now, i changed "Database.java" to "database.java" and just kept the normal**

```
 Intent startListItem = new Intent("com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining." + item.toUpperCase());
```

and

```
    <activity
                android:name=".databases"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining.DATABASES" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
```

So thanks guys!

Comment: try changing database to Databases in your stuff array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to start the activity "com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining.database" and as I see the proper activity name would be "com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining.Databases".

proper stuff definition:

```
String[] stuff = new String[] { "Databases" };
```

But a full Manifest.xml would be helpful.

The Intent creation using reflection:

```
Intent startListItem = new Intent(this, Class.forName("com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining." + item.toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: Did that then it gave me an error to put it in a try and catch also did that and then i got this error; 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining.DATABASES

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
Intent startListItem = new Intent("com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining","com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining." + item.toUpperCase());
```

?

Comment: and every class inside package com.grumbledorf.Hellotraining are in manifest ?